# PXE boot installation issues with SCCM 2012 R2

Tags: pxe-boot, sccm-2012-r2

I have taken a machine, named it IMG-2 and placed it on the domain. The machine was discovered in SCCM. I then added it to a collection and deployed a task sequence to it. However, when I then try to PXE boot that machine I get the following error:

> Architecture: 64
>
> The details below show the information relating to the PXE boot request for this computer. Please provide these
>   details to your windows deployment services Administrator so that this request can be approved.
>
> Pending Request ID:6
>
> Message From Administrator:
>      Configuration Manager is looking for policy.
>
> Contacting Server: 10.3.10.93.
>   PXE Boot aborted. Booting to next device...

When I look in SMSPXE.log this is what I am seeing

> Prioritizing local MP http://SCCM-SERVER.
>   F8:BC:12:69:02:2B, 4C4C4544-0051-5710-8036-B3C04F4D3032: No boot action. Aborted.
>   F8:BC:12:69:02:2B, 4C4C4544-0051-5710-8036-B3C04F4D3032: Not serviced.
>   Prioritizing local MP http://SCCM-SERVER.
>   Client boot action reply: `<ClientIDReply><Identification Unknown="0" ItemKey="16777585" ServerName=""><Machine><ClientID/><NetbiosName/></Machine></Identification><PXEBootAction LastPXEAdvertisementID="" LastPXEAdvertisementTime="" OfferID="" OfferIDTime="" PkgID="" PackageVersion="" PackagePath="" BootImageID="" Mandatory=""/></ClientIDReply>`
>   F8:BC:12:69:02:2B, 4C4C4544-0051-5710-8036-B3C04F4D3032: no advertisements found

It was looking to me like the MAC address wasn't properly assigned to the machine so I manually imported the machine using the name IMG-2 and the MAC address, but the error is the same doing it that way.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.